# Docker pull image without ssl in Kubernetes with docker private registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When I try to deploy something with docker registry I every time view errors:

> x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.2.10.7 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Question:
How I can disable `ssl` from deploy image in docker registry to Kubernetes ?

Comment: Are you using private docker registry ?

Comment: yes I use docker private registry

Comment: Are you using self signed certificate?

Comment: Yes. I used that comand openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -x509 -days 365 -keyout /etc/pki/tls/private/registry.key -out /etc/pki/tls/registry.crt

Comment: What exactly command have you used?

Comment: If you interested. I resolved. The reason was with certificate. The best choice it is use Letsencrypt.

Comment: You still might need to use self-signed TLS certificates. Let's encrypt tells you how. https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using self signed TLS certificate, you need to add the certificate to the known certificates list.

Grab you `.crt` file and cope it to the client machine's `ssl` certificates directory.

---

For `ubuntu`:

```sh
$ sudo cp registry.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/registry.crt 
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Now `restart` docker:

```sh
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

---

For `CentOS 7`:

1. copy the certificate inside `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`
2. Use `update-ca-trust` command

Comment: Cool. But if I am using Centos 7 ?

Comment: Yes I have seen it. But it is not helped me. Error doesn't contain any IP SANs when I tryed to deploy pod. I think maybe regeneret certificate

Comment: I don't have enough experience with centOS, sorry :(

Comment: If you interested. I resolved. The reason was with certificate. The best choice it is use Letsencrypt.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming relaxed security is OK for your environment, a way to accomplish *in Kubernetes* what you  want is to configure Docker to connect to the private registry as an insecure registry.

Per the [doc here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/):

> With insecure registries enabled, Docker goes through the following
>   steps:
>
> - First, try using HTTPS. If HTTPS is available but the certificate is invalid, ignore the error about the certificate.
> - If HTTPS is not available, fall back to HTTP.

Notice that the change to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` described in that doc - adding "insecure-registries" configuration - has to be applied to all nodes in the Kubernetes cluster on which pods/containers can be scheduled to run. Plus, Docker has to be restarted for the change to take effect.

It is also to note that the above assumes the cluster uses the Docker container runtime and not some other runtime (e.g. CRI-O) that supports the Docker image format and registry.

Comment: If you interested. I resolved. The reason was with certificate. The best choice it is use Letsencrypt.

Comment: Glad to hear, thanks for sharing. Yes, it was a problem with the validity of the certificate and the solution I proposed was to configure Docker to accept the invalid certificate...if relaxed security was OK for the environment.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with certificates because I used self-signed `TLS` certificates. It is not good idea. You might encounter with known certificates list and you will need to add certificates each time and use command `update-ca-certificates` (if you are using Centos 7). However, you might encounter another issue with certificates with another error code.

To resolve this issue i've used 3rd party Certificate Authority called [Let'sEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).